# How to convert an SVG file to one with embdedded styling properties?

Tags: css, flutter, svg, flutter-layout, adobe-illustrator

I am using the flutter svg package and it doesn't support the `<style>` element that Illustrator exports an SVG with.

Is there a way I can convert this SVG to embed these styles into their respective elements? The style tag has a bunch of classes like `cls-1`, `cls-2`, etc.

Otherwise is there a way I can export an SVG without the `<style>` tag in Illustrator?

Comment: Show examples of the svg files what you have and what you want to get. Probably it can be solved with just RegEx text replacing in the files after export.

Comment: Examples of the scripts that make text replacements within saved SVG files are here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72236750/14265469

Comment: @YuriKhristich Yes I have seen those parsers, that wouldn't be viable for a variety of SVG files from around the internet that I would edit. So it would seem the better route would be to export with inline from the get go. Unless there is a smart versatile tool that does all of it. I should check out svgcleaner later on if it is an issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going the conversion route, I've found a simple solution regarding Illustrator. When you export to an SVG, the dialog box that shows has a dropdown that let's you select `Inline Attributes`. This works with the flutter svg package perfectly.